# Кеширование данных и обновление

Tags: javascript, mongodb, кэширование

У меня есть коллекция в mongoDB, я хочу чтобы клиент единожды загрузил ее в кеш и использовал эти данные. 
Но переодически  коллекция обновляется. 
Как мне правильно реализовать обновление кеша?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Service Worker'ом и IndexDB

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо. А где можно подробнее об этом почитать? А то я с кешем вообще не работал и с Service Worker'ом

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers